# Does it risk if use c++ std::unordered_map like this?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Does it risk if use c++ std::unordered_map like this?

```
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<SomeType>>> _some_map;
   ...
   void init() {
       auto item = std::make_shared<SomeType>();
       _some_map["circle"].insert(item);
   }
```

_some_map is a member variable. init() function can be called only once, so insert is thread-safe. After initialization, the map will be read only in multi-thread. I think it is thread-safe too.

I'm not sure if I can use insert like this. Because it will make a unordered_set and a pair when there is no val of key "circle". The code works normally. Just want to make sure it is without potential risk.

(I am not good at English writing. )

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If English is not your native language can you find someone else who can translate your question for you into clear English. If you are asking whether the shown code is thread-safe, no it's not.

Comment: That code is threads-safe, @SamVarshavchik, where do you see problems running it in multiple threads?

Comment: What kind of risk you are asking for? In these 3 lines of code I don't see anything unusual or unsafe. Just be aware that `operator[]` default-creates new map element if one does not exist.

Comment: @ulrich -- can you find me anything in the specification of `unordered_map` or `unordered_set` that specifies that these containers are thread safe? This is a trick question: you won't. None of the containers in the C++ library guarantee thread-safety. It's up to you to make them thread safe, yourself. That's incorrect. `map["circle"].insert(item);` is not thread-safe.

Comment: All containers in the standard library are thread-safe, @SamVarshavchik. I guess you mean that concurrent accesses to the same instance is safe, but that's not the same as thread-safe.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thread-safe means concurrent accesses to the same instances are safe, which they are not!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You should explain what you call thread-safety, otherwise pedantry is of no use.

Comment: It's not a quote directly from the standard, but check out the box on thread safety at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Are you miss-reading this part _"...All container functions can be called concurrently by different threads on __different containers__...."_ not the same container ?  If not which part in the box does guarantee _"...All containers in the standard library are thread-safe..."_ ?

Comment: BTW, getting pedantic, the above code only directly accesses local variables. The only shared state with other threads is via allocators, and those accesses are synchronized. So the above code is formally thread-safe. I would never make that claim though, because it's a fragment without context that doesn't allow making any statements concerning the program it's from.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Since OP resizes the container, the only thing they can do concurrently is (1): work with other containers concurrently. This is an extremely weak definition of thread-safety.

Comment: Those other containers, they could even be created and subsequently resized by calling the above code from a different thread, exactly because the above code is thread-safe. I'm specifically not making any claims concerning code that is not above. Code is thread-safe when it can be called from multiple threads without causing UB (I think that's a reasonable definition) and the above qualifies for that.

Comment: @Anna, it would really help if you clarified your question. For guidance, also take the [tour] and especially read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I can use insert like this.

Yes, you can, because [operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at)

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

Your `value_type` is `std::unordered_set` which is default constructible, so there is no problem.

> After initialization, the map will be read only in multi-thread

Here also you are safe, because according to the [containers documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

> All const member functions can be called concurrently by different threads on the same container.

so if you are only reading the values without modifying them, it is OK. You could even perform write operations if you could guarantee that different threads are accessing different elements in your container.

Comment: If I need to edit val of "circle" and val of same other key at the same time, maybe I should make sure not to read them concurrently?

Comment: If you want to just do `map["key1"] = xxx;` and `map["key2"] = yyy;` in parallel - it is fine, because (look in the table in the documentation) references in map are valid after insertion (which can potentially happen when using `operator[]`). If you have in mind some more complex operation, like reading and writing to unknown elements, from different threads, then it's a specific problem that requires manual synchronization.